# Android - No error but failed to insert fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a newbie in Android app, and I'm now trying to insert a fragment into `<FrameLayout>`. This is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ycl.com.remotearduino.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_settings.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ho man!" />

</FrameLayout>
```

part of SettingsFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_settings, container, false);
}
```

part of onCreate of MainActivity.java:

```
SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, settingsFragment).commit();
```

When I run the app, there's no error, but the fragment does not show up at all. Does anybody have an idea why it's so?

***Edit***: I noticed that the method inflate in the onCreateView is not executed at all as I'm now in DEBUG mode but the tag "LayoutInflator" does not show up. It should print 'INFLATING from resource: ...' according to the LayoutInflater source code...

***Edit***: onCreateView() is indeed executed, but still, no sign of the inflate() method...

Comment: it seems all ok....are you using  android.support.v4.app.Fragment and where you put this code in main activity

Comment: Yes, I'm using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. I put the last code segment in the `onCreate()` method of MainActivity.java.

Comment: try changing textview's textcolor or set background to FrameLayout content_settings.xml and then run your code.

Comment: Oh it shows up indeed! Upon inspecting the frames on the android device, it is the problem of the frame layout: It fills up the whole screen, and the text is hidden behind the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @KaranMer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your FrameLayout:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Your SettingsFragment is visible but the text in it are behind toolbar due to CoordinatorLayout.Try adding more text and you will see.To fix this issue use the above solution.

Comment: This is it! I have just realized the problem as well and was trying to use marginTop LOL. Your solution is clearly a more elegant one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_settings, container, false);
```

to this

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

Comment: Tried this, but it's the same as before. I have a question though. What I intend to do is insert the fragment, which is content_settings.xml, into the content_frame in the app_bar_main.xml, which is in turn included by activity_main.xml. Why do I have use activity_main as the resource argument?